# java programming, writing to text files

Tags: java

how do i make this code write to the text file height.txt? it creates it but it doesnt write to it.
and it also compiles and says data is written to the file but there isnt any data when i open the file why is that?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class readinguserinput {

    public static String gender;
    public static int motherHeight;
    public static int fatherHeight;
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("height.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        System.out.println ("Enter gender");
        gender = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println ("Enter Mother Height");
        motherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();

        keyboard.nextLine();

        while (motherHeight < 0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter Mother Height");
            motherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println ("Enter father Height");
        fatherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (fatherHeight < 0)
        {       System.out.println ("Enter Father Height");
            fatherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        pw.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

        System.out.println("data written to the file");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code never writes anything to the file.  Try `pw.print()` and `pw.println()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
System.out...
```

To:

```
pw.out...
```

You are currently writing output to the console, not your PrintWriter

Comment: He is writing console output to the console. If he follows this advice he will lose his UI.

Comment: He doesn't need to change any of the ones he wrote. They are all clearly intended for the console. He needs to add new ones, that include the values being read from the console. Neither a loaf nor even breadcrumbs here.

Answer (score 0):

Your program just prints what you tell it to print. In this case you told it to print 'data written to the file', but you didn't tell it to actually *write* anything to the file. Your program lied to you, on your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Sample program to write a text file,

```
String content = "This is the content to write into file";

File file = new File("/data/filename.txt");

// if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
bufferedWriter.write(content);
bufferedWriter.close();
```

Refer: [How to write text file in Java ...](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @benka I have included the sample code. Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0):

As stated before. You haven't actually written anything to your file.
Try this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class readinguserinput {

public static String gender;
public static int motherHeight;
public static int fatherHeight;
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("height.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    System.out.println ("Enter gender");        
    gender = keyboard.next();
    pw.println("Gender: " + gender); // ***************
    System.out.println ("Enter Mother Height");
    motherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();        
    pw.println("motherHeight: " + motherHeight); // ***************
    keyboard.nextLine();

    while (motherHeight < 0)
    {
        System.out.println ("Enter Mother Height");
        motherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        pw.println("motherHeight: " + motherHeight); // ***************

    }
    System.out.println ("Enter father Height");
    fatherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
    pw.println("fatherHeight: " + fatherHeight); // ***************
    while (fatherHeight < 0)
    {       System.out.println ("Enter Father Height");
            fatherHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
            pw.println("fatherHeight: " + fatherHeight); // ***************
    }

    pw.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

    System.out.println("data written to the file");}}
```